# Rails loop through ActiveRecord::Associations:CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got a `ActiveRecord::Associations:CollectionProxy` of the format

`#<DailyViewMetric article_id: xxxxxx, date: xxxxxxx, views: xxxxxx, visitors xxxxx,.....>` in a variable called `metrics`.

The article_id is a foreign key and is repeated in the table (as one article can have metrics on consecutive days (i.e. 15 views today and 20 the day after).

I need a way to loop through this and apply different operations to some of these metrics like get the smallesest date for each article, the total number of views (= sum(views)). I tried `metrics.map do |a|` and `metrics.collect` but always just get ruby errors `undefined method 'views'` For example let's go with the following simplified dataset

```
article_id date         views
1          2014-01-01   10
2          2014-01-01   15
1          2014-01-02   20
2          2014-01-02   12
3          2014-01-02   6
```

should result in the following new array afterwards:

```
article_id date         views
1          2014-01-01   30
2          2014-01-01   27
3          2014-01-02   6
```

as you can see the views variable holds the sum of the views for that respective article, the date variable is the minimum of the dates. How do I do this properly? I also tried `metrics.to_a` but I still get this error.

EDIT

I tried `DailyViewMetric.find_by_sql("SELECT article_id, sum(views) from daily_view_metrics where article_id in(SELECT id from articles where user_id=xxx) GROUP BY article_id")`

which, if i execute the query in the mysql console, works perfectly fine and returns the second table from up above. but when I run it in the rails console it gives me

```
[#<DailyViewMetric id: nil, article_id: 1089536>, #<DailyViewMetric id: nil, article_id: 1128849>, #<DailyViewMetric id: nil, article_id: 1141623>,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this completely in SQL/ActiveRecord. The query you want to run ultimately is

```
SELECT article_id, min(date), sum(views)
FROM   daily_value_metrics -- Or whatever your table is called
GROUP BY article_id
```

You can run this with ActiveRecord with the following:

```
table = DailyValueMetric.arel_table
results = DailyValueMetric.select(table[:article_id], 
  table[:date].minimum.as('date'), 
  table[:views].sum.as('views')).group(:article_id).to_a
# Calling to_a so I can call first for the example
results.first.date #=> date
results.first.views #=> views
results.first.article_id #=> Id
```

The records will look like

```
[#<DailyViewMetric id: nil, article_id: 1089536>, ...]
```

Because the SQL query does not return an id column in the result set. This is because of the way that `ActiveRecord::Base#inspect` shows the columns defined on the table, and not the returned values outside of the table columns. Views and Date will not necessarily be shown, unless there is a column with the same name, but if you call those attributes on the model instance, you will be able to get the value

Comment: I tried this already, and if I query the sql in my sql console it works fine but when I do it in find_by_sql("...") I get odd `nil` and other values returned as well as for completely different column names`

Comment: So, since you aren't selecting the parts you need to complete the record, they will be nil, but you should be able to get the columns you create for the attributes you select

Comment: I edited the question, see above, the result form the find_by_sql query in rails is just bizzare...

Comment: TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

from that code, it looks like what i need exactly though...

Comment: @Killerpixler: Ah, my ActiveRecord example won't work for your specific case because of the subquery

Comment: Yeah I went with the find_by_sql() and used `sum(views) as views` and now it returns the views properly. Thanks